# How to write the CASE Statement syntax for this logic in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, case

I am using SQL Server 2014 and I have the following table (called NonRoomBundle) in my SQL database, of which an extract is shown below:

```
  ResaID       StayDate                  BundleDate                   BundleID
  50         NULL                       2016-03-03 00:00:00.000         123
  50         2016-02-28 00:00:00.000    NULL                              3
  50         2016-02-29 00:00:00.000    NULL                              3
  50         2016-03-01 00:00:00.000    NULL                              3
  50         2016-03-02 00:00:00.000    NULL                              3
  50         2016-03-03 00:00:00.000    NULL                              3
  50         2016-03-04 00:00:00.000    NULL                              3
  50         2016-03-05 00:00:00.000    NULL                              3
  50         2016-03-02 00:00:00.000    NULL                              3
  56         NULL                       2016-04-02 00:00:00.000         120
  56         2016-04-01 00:00:00.000    NULL                             25
  56         2016-04-02 00:00:00.000    NULL                             25
  56         2016-04-03 00:00:00.000    NULL                             25
```

The BundleDate column shows the effective StayDate from which the BundleId should be 123.

I need to to write a query that will provide me the following output:

```
ResaID       StayDate                    BundleDate                   BundleID
  50         NULL                       2016-03-03 00:00:00.000         123
  50         2016-02-28 00:00:00.000    NULL                              3
  50         2016-02-29 00:00:00.000    NULL                              3
  50         2016-03-01 00:00:00.000    NULL                              3
  50         2016-03-02 00:00:00.000    NULL                              3
  50         2016-03-03 00:00:00.000    NULL                            123
  50         2016-03-04 00:00:00.000    NULL                            123
  50         2016-03-05 00:00:00.000    NULL                            123
  50         2016-03-02 00:00:00.000    NULL                            123
  56         NULL                       2016-04-02 00:00:00.000         120
  56         2016-04-01 00:00:00.000    NULL                             25
  56         2016-04-02 00:00:00.000    NULL                            120
  56         2016-04-03 00:00:00.000    NULL                            120
```

As shown above the BundleId becomes 123 as from '2016-03-02' which is the BundleDate.
My little knowledge of SQL tells me a CASE statement should do the trick but I am having a hard time writing it. I have reached this far:

```
SELECT StayDate
      ,BundleDate
      ,(CASE WHEN BundleDate >= StayDate THEN ....
   FROM NonRoomBundle
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are after?

```
with NonRoomBundle  (StayDate, BundleDate , BundleID)
as
(
select NULL as StayDate, '2016-03-02 00:00:00.000' as BundleDate , 123 as BundleID
union
select '2016-02-28 00:00:00.000' as StayDate, NULL as BundleDate , 3 as BundleID
union
select '2016-02-29 00:00:00.000' as StayDate, NULL as BundleDate , 3 as BundleID
union
select '2016-03-01 00:00:00.000' as StayDate, NULL as BundleDate , 3 as BundleID
union
select '2016-03-02 00:00:00.000' as StayDate, NULL as BundleDate , 3 as BundleID
union
select '2016-03-03 00:00:00.000' as StayDate, NULL as BundleDate , 3 as BundleID
union
select '2016-03-04 00:00:00.000' as StayDate, NULL as BundleDate , 3 as BundleID
union
select '2016-03-05 00:00:00.000' as StayDate, NULL as BundleDate , 3 as BundleID
)   

SELECT StayDate
,BundleDate
,(
 CASE 
WHEN StayDate < (select max(BundleDate ) from NonRoomBundle) THEN 3
else 123
END
)
FROM NonRoomBundle
```

Comment: Also, I don't want to put an explicit value for BundleID as I will need to run it through the whole table. I've shown only an extract of the Table in my question.

Comment: Can you supply more data examples?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
declare @tblInput table (ResaID int, StayDate datetime, BundleDate datetime, BundleID int)

insert into @tblInput(ResaID, StayDate, BundleDate, BundleID)
values  (50, NULL, '2016-03-07', 123),
        (50,'2016-02-28', NULL, 3),
        (50,'2016-02-29', NULL, 3),
        (50,'2016-03-01', NULL, 3),
        (50,'2016-03-02', NULL, 3),
        (50,'2016-03-03', NULL, 3),
        (50,'2016-03-04', NULL, 3),
        (50,'2016-03-05', NULL, 3),
        (50,'2016-03-02', NULL, 3),
        (56,NULL, '2016-04-02', 120),
        (56,'2016-04-01', NULL, 25),
        (56,'2016-04-02', NULL, 25),
        (56,'2016-04-03', NULL, 25)

;WITH cte (ResaID, StayDate, BundleDate, BundleID)
as 
(
    select ResaID, StayDate, BundleDate, BundleId 
        from @tblInput 
    where BundleDate is not null
)
SELECT t1.ResaID
      ,t1.StayDate
      ,t1.BundleDate
      ,ISNULL(t2.BundleID, t1.BundleID) as BundleID
   FROM @tblInput t1
   left join cte t2 on t2.BundleDate <= ISNULL(t1.StayDate, GETDATE()) 
                       and t1.ResaID = t2.ResaID;
```

What I have done is: first separate the values with bundle dates (anchor rows) and then I've joined with the initial table with the `on` clause that you provided in the `case` clause. You can replace the `GETDATE()` from the `ISNULL` function with a more viable date based on your requirements.

**EDIT**: I've updated the code.
**EDIT2**: I've updated the code to reflect what you need.

Comment: Thanks. I have updated my question with additional info. I made an error in BundleDate and I have now corrected it. Can you please have a look.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. Your solution is doing the inverse of what I am looking for. It is replacing the values of BundleID of all those records where the BundleDate is LESS than the StayDate instead of GREATER than the StayDate. I think something needs to be tweaked as what you proposed is very near the correct solution.

Comment: Ok I got it. I just needed to replace the >= by <=. Can you edit your solution so that I can vote for it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

This may seem convoluted, and there might be another way than what I'm proposing, but here's one way to skin this cat:

```
declare @bundleDates table (
    BundleDate date,
    BundleID int,
    RunningNo int
)

insert into @bundleDates
select
    BundleDate,
    BundleID,
    row_number() over (order by (select null))
from NonRoomBundle
where BundleDate is not null order by BundleDate asc

declare @NonRoomBundle table (
    StayDate date,
    BundleDate date,
    BundleID int
)

declare
    @tmpBundleDate date,
    @tmpBundleID int,
    @tmpRunningNo int

declare cur cursor local for select BundleDate, BundleID, RunningNo from @bundleDates
open cur
fetch next from cur into @tmpBundleDate, @tmpBundleID, @tmpRunningNo
while @@fetch_status = 0
    begin
        if exists (select RunningNo from @bundleDates where RunningNo = @tmpRunningNo + 1)
            begin
                declare @currBundleDate date, @nextBundleDate date
                set @currBundleDate = @tmpBundleDate
                set @nextBundleDate = (select BundleDate from @bundleDates where RunningNo = @tmpRunningNo + 1)

                insert into @NonRoomBundle
                select
                    StayDate,
                    BundleDate,
                    BundleID
                from NonRoomBundle
                where
                    StayDate is null
                    and BundleID = @tmpBundleID

                union

                select
                    StayDate,
                    BundleDate,
                    case
                        when StayDate < @currBundleDate then BundleID
                        when StayDate >= @currBundleDate then @tmpBundleID
                    end as BundleID
                from NonRoomBundle
                where
                    StayDate is not null
                    and year(StayDate) <= year(@currBundleDate)
                    and month(StayDate) <= month(@currBundleDate)
                    and StayDate < @nextBundleDate
            end
        else
            begin
                insert into @NonRoomBundle
                select
                    StayDate,
                    BundleDate,
                    BundleID
                from NonRoomBundle
                where
                    StayDate is null
                    and BundleID = @tmpBundleID

                union

                select
                    StayDate,
                    BundleDate,
                    case
                        when StayDate < @tmpBundleDate then BundleID
                        when StayDate >= @tmpBundleDate then @tmpBundleID
                    end as BundleID
                from NonRoomBundle
                where
                    StayDate is not null
                    and year(StayDate) >= year(@tmpBundleDate)
                    and month(StayDate) >= month(@tmpBundleDate)
            end

        fetch next from cur into @tmpBundleDate, @tmpBundleID, @tmpRunningNo
    end
close cur
deallocate cur


select * from @NonRoomBundle
```